# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь получить информацию о сервере от Steam:

```
from steam import game_servers as gs
import steam

WoVN1 = next(gs.query_master(r'\appid\892970\gameaddr\АДРЕС'))
print(gs.a2s_info(WoVN1['player']))
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
    print(gs.a2s_info(WoVN1['player']))
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Пробовал приписывать `int`, не помогает. Подозреваю, что нужно будет использовать `row`..

Comment: посмотрите, что у вас в WoVN1?

Comment: @Jack_oS `{'_ping': 24.008750915527344, '_type': 'source', 'protocol': 17, 'name': '[RU] <color=#48B695>WoV #1</color> - Open', 'map': '[RU] <color=#48B695>WoV #1</col', 'folder': 'valheim', 'game': 'Valheim', 'app_id': 892970, 'players': 19, 'max_players': 20, 'bots': 0, 'server_type': 'd', 'environment': 'w', 'visibility': 0, 'vac': 0, 'version': '1.0.0.0', 'edf': 177, 'port': 2457, 'steam_id': 90144051586794504, 'keywords': '0.147.3', 'game_id': 892970}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

замените

```
print(gs.a2s_info(WoVN1['player']))
```

на

```
print(gs.a2s_info(WoVN1)['players'])
```